# how to obtain a particular value from a map(string,string) field?

Tags: sql, dictionary, hive, hiveql

I have a table with the following two columns [image]

The format of event_detail column is map(string,string)

I want to obtain the visitor numbers who have value(B) in the event_detail

[image]

Comment: @Dudu Markovitz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query rows `where event_detail["value(B)"] is not null`:

```
select visitor_number
  from table
where event_detail["value(B)"] is not null
```

**Demo:**

Create test table:

```
hive> create table test_t(visitor_number int,event_detail map<string,string>);
OK
```

load data:

```
hive> insert into test_t select 123, map("value(B)","Bye") union all  select 123, map("value(G)","Jet");
OK
```

Select rows with value(B):

```
hive> select visitor_number from test_t where event_detail["value(B)"] is not null;
OK
123
```